# Cramer's rule doesn't work here?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I tried to solve the following system:

$$A_2\cdot 2\mathrm{i}\sin( \beta a) = B_3\exp(- \alpha a)$$
$$\mathrm{i} \beta A_2 2\cos( \beta a) = - \alpha B_3\exp(- \alpha a)$$

Then I got $A_2=0  \Rightarrow B_3=0$ which is impossible, because it's a system of wave functions of a particle with potential:
$$
V(x) =
\begin{cases}
  \infty, & x < 0 \\
  0, & 0 < x < a \\
  V_0, & x > a
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: If the unknowns are $A_2$ and $B_3$ then there will only be a nontrivial solution for certain values of $\alpha,\beta,a$, namely when the matrix of the linear system is singular.

Comment: i can't  understand
 \alpha and \beta are constants 
A_2 and B_3 are unknows only

Comment: ....Yes, but depending on the actual values of those constants, you may or may not have a solution other than $A_2=B_3=0$. If that is a problem, then you have made an error further back.

Comment: actually 
 \alpha ^2 = (2m/h^2)*(V_0-E)
\beta ^2 =(2m/h^2)*E
and a is a width

Comment: My guess is that you have added an assumption earlier in your calculation which turned out not to be justified. Either that, or $-2i\sin(\beta a) \alpha \exp(-\alpha a)+2i \beta \cos(\beta a) \exp(-\alpha a)$ has to be zero, which I guess means $\alpha \sin(\beta a)=\beta \cos(\beta a)$.